# How to convert long minutes to hours in excel

Tags: excel, time

I need a formula in excel to convert minutes to hours. Until now came the following formula:

=A1/1440

So, 180minutes its converted to 03:00, when formatted as hh:mm

But, i need also to convert long minutes, like 1600. In this case, the formula converts to 02:40, when it should show 26:40.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
=INT(A1/60)&":" &MOD(A1,60)
```

and `=TEXT(FLOOR(A1/60,1),"00")&":"&TEXT(MOD(A1,60),"00")` for Format hh:mm

Answer (score 2):

Use exactly the same formula you are using now, but change the display format to:
    `[h]:mm:ss`

That will display in the format you want AND allow you to perform operations on the values.

( With format showing in the top of the time columns)

```
 [h]:mm:ss        hh:mm:ss        Equal?
=1600/1440      =1600/1440      =G23=F23
=F23+1600/1440  =G23+1600/1440  =G24=F24
```

Gives

```
[h]:mm:ss   hh:mm:ss    Equal?
26:40:00    2:40:00     TRUE
53:20:00    5:20:00     TRUE
```